# How to identify index based off of specific values in specific columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a list of indexes that have a specific column and value

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df['A'] = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']
df['B'] = ['Car', 'Truck', 'Car']
df['C'] = ['California', 'Nevada', 'Florida']
df['D'] = ['Coffee', 'Juice', 'Water']
df['E'] = ['Arm', 'Leg', 'Head']
```

How would I get the index for list of columns 'A', 'B', 'D' that contain the list of values 'Cat', 'Car', and 'Coffee'? In this example the index should be 0

Comment: Check `df[df[['A', 'B', 'D']].eq(['Cat', 'Car', 'Coffee']).all(1)].index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order of values is not important and not duplicates seelct columns by list and test by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) if match all values, last filter index values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
i = df.index[df[['A', 'B', 'D']].isin(['Cat','Car','Coffee']).all(axis=1)]
print (i)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

If order is important you can compare values by list in [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
i = df.index[df[['A', 'B', 'D']].eq(['Cat', 'Car', 'Coffee']).all(axis=1)]
print (i)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

If need scalar working also if no match then use:

```
out = next(iter(i), 'no match')
```